# Add (Insert) Primary Key column to DataTable in C# and VB.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

**How to Add (Insert) Primary Key column to DataTable in C# and VB.Net**

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 
//Add columns to DataTable.
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Country") });

 
//Add rows to DataTable.
dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
```

How to add Primary key in given datatable.when i want to id column
is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//Add columns to DataTable.
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Country") });

//Set the Primary Key Column.
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["Id"] };

//Add rows to DataTable.
dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create table in database like this

```
create table tablename 
(
     id **primary key auto increment**, 
     name varchar(255), 
     country varchar(255)
)
```

Then you pass only name and country like this

```
dt.Rows.Add( "John Hammond", "United States");
dt.Rows.Add( "Mudassar Khan", "India");
dt.Rows.Add( "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
dt.Rows.Add( "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
```

Your id is automatically inserted in database as a primary key.

In DataTable you insert Primary key like this

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("childTable");
    DataColumn column;    
    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType= System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    column.ColumnName = "ChildID";
    column.AutoIncrement = true;
    column.Caption = "ID";
    column.ReadOnly = true;
    column.Unique = true;
table.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: it is right but some times our requirement is primary key in datatable

Comment: See edit i will update my code

Comment: Thanks @ malik farhan

Comment: welcome if this is the right answer than mark the answer